# How to loop check and iterate inside a hash to create/populate key value pairs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have something like

```
strands = Strand.all


data = {}
data["data"] = {
              strands.each do |strand|
                "#{strand.name}" = {"description" => "#{strand.description}",
                                     if strand.standards.present?
                                        "children" => 
                                        strand.standards.each do |standard|
                                            {"#{standard.name}" => {"description" => "#{standard.description}"}
                                          }
                                        end
                                      end
                                    } 
              end
}
```

So I need to generate a json structure like the one below

```
"data": {
     "testStrand3Code": {
            "description" : " some descr.. .",
            "children" : {"standard3Code" : {
                "description" : " some descr.. ."
            }}
      }
}
```

Im not able to iterate `strands.each do |strand|` and its giving me an error. I think i cant run logic code inside a hash{} ? How do I go about this? Thank You.

Comment: Sure you can. What _is_ the error? Please share the error message at least. (Also, I bet it should be `map`, not `each`.)

Comment: @mudasobwa This is the error: SyntaxError
/Users/Chetan/rails_workspace/curriculum-content-lib/app/controllers/api/v1/curriculum_services_controller.rb:44: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting keyword_end "#{strand.name}" = {"description" => "#{strand.d ^ /Users/Chetan/rails_workspace/curriculum-content-lib/app/controllers/api/v1/curriculum_services_controller.rb

Comment: (1) You build a hash, `data["data"] = {...}`, but inside the curlies, you don't have key/value pairs. (2) You have a string literal to the left of an assignment: `"#{strand.name}" = ....`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(data = {})["data"] =
  strands.map do |strand|
    [strand.name, 
      {
        "description" => strand.description,
        "children" => strand.standards.map do |standard|
          [standard.name, {"description" => standard.description}]
        end.to_h
      }
    ]
  end.to_h
```

Comment: Thanks a lot? 0.o